# Android fileprovider issue over 26+

Tags: android, uri

Could you give an advice for this?
I really don't understand why this issue is not clear.
Here is my error message from android studio.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/7853 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.alibaba.food/com.alibaba.food.market.MarketRegActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/food/msg/tmp_1542878122647.jpg
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4491)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1752)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/food/msg/tmp_1542878122647.jpg
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at com.alibaba.food.market.MarketRegActivity.createSaveCropFile(MarketRegActivity.java:447)
        at com.alibaba.food.market.MarketRegActivity.onActivityResult(MarketRegActivity.java:337)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7556)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4487)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4534) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1752) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I usually works under 21 build version.
This is my first time to build over 26+.

My file provider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="files" path="images/media/" /> <!-- Context.getFilesDir(). -->
    <cache-path name="images" path="./images" /><!-- getCacheDir(). -->
    <external-path name="name" path="path" /> <!-- Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). -->
    <external-files-path name="storage/emulated" path="food/msg/" /> <!-- Context#getExternalFilesDir(String) Context.getExternalFilesDir(null). -->
    <external-cache-path name="storage/emulated" path="." /> <!-- Context.getExternalCacheDir(). -->
</paths>
```

My uri java code :

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/food/msg/");
if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
    dir.mkdir();
}
Uri uri;
String url = "tmp_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";

filename = url;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { // API 24 +..
        String strpa = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", 
                new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                         + "/food/msg/" + url));
} else {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(
                new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() 
                         + "/food/msg/" + url));
}
```

My manifest :

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.alibaba.food.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the image file from a location?

Comment: Oh my god!!! I just removed ".path()" from "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()". I can resolve my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

add to manifest

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.vansuita.pickimage.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/picker_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

change the authorities name

Comment: Hello Shahriyar, Unfortunately I've already added provider into manifest. The result of building is same problem occurring.

Comment: Oh my god!!! I just removed ".path()" from "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()". I can resolve my problem. Thank you :)